# AI/EPS file opens different on another computer?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, canvas

I designed a logo in AI and when I open it on my computer, everything is in order. The proportion, the text, no errors what so ever.

However when I open the file on another computer it looks like this: [image]

**edit**: Sorry I didn't mention earlier that what is different from my original version is that the text: DIEKLI is suppose to say DIEKLIMA. Upon opening it on another computer, the text seems to be cut off as if it is a different size. But I already have it as an outline (or a shape... however it is called) so it is not a matter of changing the text size?

Can somebody please explain to me why there is suddenly a difference when the file has not been changed?

Comment: How does it look different? As far as we can tell, this is how it's supposed to look. Add an image of how it *should* look as well.

Comment: Hmmm . . .  it doesn't look like you converted the text to outlines. That tiny red quare with a plus sign at the right hand side means that text is overflowing the text box - and that only happens with editable text, not outlines.

Comment: @BillyKerr I checked my file again and it now tells me it WAS a text. Even though I am certain I made it an outline before... However, since that new discover (lol), the problem seems to be fixed now that it is offically an outline. Thanks you for your time!

Comment: @ElizaBeth - no problems. Glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious problem with the font.

Did you embed the font at the EPS?

[image: Eps window]

The best option in a logo is outlining the text.

Selecting the text, **Menu Type** > **Create Outlines**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I edited my origianl post with some more details I realised I forgot to add. Yes, I did have the embed fonts setting on. I did change the text into an outline. Is there anything else that could be wrong with the file? :/ It worked all fine before. It is just suddenly weird on the other computer.

Comment: If the text it's outlined as you say is impossible to see the hyphenation dash because it is not a text anymore, something is wrong in your file or your procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I actually didn't know that about the text (there are some parts of AI that still confuses me). Turns out there was some sort of error with my file, because now it tells me it WAS indeed a text. After changing it to an outline, everything seems to be normal again. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the same version of that font is installed on both computers.
2. Reset AI preferences on the second computer. Some default setting on the second computer may override the formatting in your original AI file.
3. Ultimately, convert the font to outlines on your computer. Normally logos should be converted to outlines, which removes the possibility to edit text, but also removes possible errors like yours when opening on different machines.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the time and advice. I did all the things you mentioned. Turns out there was indeed some sort of error because after checking the files again this morning, it tells me it was indeed a text file (I swear I changed it before...) and now after converting it into an outline everything seems to be fine and dandy. FINGERS CROSSED!